# Why does the event handler function still works after the variable point to null?

Tags: javascript, dom

after `inputBox = null`, when I mouse over the `inputBox`, the `_countNum` still adds 1. I thought it would stop

```js
! function() {
  var _countNum = 0;
  var inputBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  inputBox.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    console.log("countNum: " + _countNum++);
    console.log(inputBox);
    inputBox = null;
  });
}();
```

```html
<input type="text" v-model="inputValue" placeholder="添加ToDo">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event listener is attached to the element in the DOM. The variable was just used temporarily to hold a reference to the element. Reassigning the variable doesn't change the element itself.

If you want to stop the event listener, use `removeEventListener`. To do this you'll need to use a named function, so you can refer to it in both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.

```js
! function() {
  var _countNum = 0;
  var inputBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  function listener () {
    console.log("countNum: " + _countNum++);
    console.log(inputBox);
    inputBox.removeEventListener("mouseover", listener);
  }
  inputBox.addEventListener("mouseover", listener);
}();
```

```html
<input type="text" v-model="inputValue" placeholder="添加ToDo">
```